# How to resize picture with a filesize restriction

Tags: php, resize

Im am using this class [verot upload class](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_docs.htm?PHPSESSID=0c063fd3e994c1b7b14061843ac1525e)

I want to resize the image for maximum 50kb after the resize.
My idea is to use a while cycle and inside the circle do a resize, save it on disc and check with php function what size the new picture has. if its bigger than 50kg, then do another circle with smaller resize values.

Do you think there is a better solution?
thanks for help

Comment: bigger than 50kg is too big :-) if it is too small what will you do? why cycle ? what type of resize params you going to pass?

Comment: just a suggestion, you might want to start small and work up to 50kb to save on server resources.

Comment: http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_forum.htm?php_class_upload_forum_id=3862

Answer (score 0):

Creator of the class here. The class already has this functionality, see the `jpeg_size` parameter. For instance:

```
$handle->jpeg_size = 50000;
```